# Can I book a two leg trip but only use the second leg?

Tags: tickets

I'm looking to book a quick one way trip from nyc to Pittsburgh.  The nonstop flights are all around $300.  When I try out of Hartford, ct...I get a flight for $150 leaving Hartford with one stop in Newark.  When I check the same exact Newark flight...its $300.

My question is...could I book the Hartford-Newark-Pittsburgh flight...but just get dropped off at Newark for the second leg, since I live closer to nyc than Hartford. To save half the price.

Are there any issues or rules against this?

Thanks

Comment: With most airlines, No. When you fail to check in for the first leg they cancel the rest of the ticket. This question is likely going to be closed as a duplicate as it has been asked and answered here before.

Comment: @JonathanReez not a dupe, yours is asking about not taking the second leg, this is asking about ONLY taking the second leg.  There's a distinct difference in airline behavior for each case.

Answer (score 2):

No. On a multi-leg flight ticket (return or multi-city), when you don't show up for any leg of the itinerary, the whole ticket is cancelled. So in practice you can only skip the last leg (or several legs at the end of a multi-city flight) of the flight (for example the return portion of a round-trip ticket).

Comment: Wow. That seems wrong to me.